# How enable OpenCL on AMD gpu Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, radeon, opencl

When I'm not using my desktop, it mines. When I was on 20.04 LTS, I used AMD's proprietary driver to install the ROCm component of their driver only, found here: https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-6000-series/amd-radeon-6700-series/amd-radeon-rx-6700-xt.

Unfortunately they only currently support 18.04.5(6) and 20.04.4. Is there a way with the open source stack only to enable opencl on an AMD gpu (I have a 6700 XT)?

Comment: I should have been more experimental, using AMDs latest driver (21.50) and installing with ```amdgpu-install --usecase=opencl --no-dkms``` works fine on 22.04.

Comment: As it turns out this is not a final solution, it causes gnome-control-center to fail to start with this error: ```gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0: undefined symbol: drmGetDeviceFromDevId
```

Comment: having the same problem. did you find a solution?

Comment: Do you dear to try Driver version 22.40.3? They have been released last week, and should have preview support for Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 5):

I just did a fresh install to a USB3.0 thumb drive using **22.04.2 LTS** and was able to get my RX 5600XT working with OpenCL. 5600XT is a Navi10, the 6700XT is a Navi22. Maybe it will work...

I grabbed the non-HME version **[22.40.3 for Ubuntu 22.04.2](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-5600-series/amd-radeon-rx-5600-series/amd-radeon-rx-5600-xt)**. dpkg -i....then:

```
root@yada:/# amdgpu-install --usecase=workstation,rocm,opencl --opencl=rocr,legacy --vulkan=pro --accept-eula
```

There was a couple messages about missing firmware in /lib/firmware/amdgpu which appears to be common but they were a handful of specific code named GPU's. Looking at that directory shows a bunch of files for many types like Pitcairn, and Navi, and Vega.

Did a reboot and **clinfo** shows the 5600XT.

If you plan on compiling things with OpenCL support such as JTR be sure to:

```
sudo apt-get -y install ocl-icd-opencl-dev opencl-headers
```

Lastly, I added my user to groups video and render but I'm not getting any devices when I run clinfo or john --list=opencl-devices. Running as root works fine. Close enough for me.

Comment: after adding your user to those groups reboot to make sure that change takes effect

Comment: I executed your installation parameters, and it worked for me without rebooting. No idea which of the parameters did the trick, but Darktable has OpenCL support again.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issues with missing packages.
So I unpacked the install.deb from AMD and extracted the repository URLs. The .deb is some kind of ZIP. The folder is etc/apt/... Putting this URLs manually to my sources.list and "apt update" and the install runs smooth.